# How does React links dependencies in `useEffect` hook to state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I imagine very good how React's "useState" hook works. State - is a list of values mapped to certain component, and theres also index of useState call, which is requesting state value index. When React renderer encouters component, it writes it into outer reference, to which useState have access, so it returns state value by useState call index, from "current" component's state list.
But I have no idea, how does React identify and link dependencies in "useEffect" to actual state which obviously is plain values like numbers and strings. How is that done?

```
import React from 'react'

function Component() {
  const [plainString, setPlainString] = React.useState('Hello')
  const [anotherPlainString, setAnotherPlainString] = React.useState('Good bye')

  // update `plainString` after mount
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setPlainString('Updated Hello')
  }, [])

  // callback get triggered after `plainString` update!
  // but how it links dependency to state if its just 'Hello' string?
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      console.log(plainString) // "Updated Hello"
    },
    [plainString]
  )

  return <h1>plainString</h1>
}
```

Comment: Hint: The state variables aren't linked to a component (per se) - the hook is. Which is why hooks must always be called in the same order and can't be called conditionally (and can't have conditional dependencies)

Comment: @Adam Okay. However in implementation that I suggested hooks can't be re-ordered too. And it works same, actually, ive tested.

Comment: I meant to say that **once mounted** the hooks for a given component can't be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simply whether the values in the dependency array change, they don't even have to be stateful.

```
useEffect(() => {

}, dependencyArray) // React loops over these values to check for changes
```

You can test this pretty easily with random numbers

```
dependencyArray = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()]
```

Which will very likely create an array with different values on rerenders.

If the first time it gets `[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]` and the next time it gets `[0.1, 0.2, 0]` It will trigger the effect again because the values in the array are not the same.

Comment: Just to add a tiny bit more detail - react links the hook to the component (through the fiber magic) so it knows the values of those dependencies the last time the effect function was ran, it has them stored in memory. It knows what the values are now (because you have supplied them!). So it's a simple loop and check to see if they are the same the last time the function was called. If yes, don't call the function, if no, call it (memoization). Here's all the [goodness](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js)

Comment: I got it, effect callback stays untouched in further renders, it just checks values from list it recieved before with new ones. So easy! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

This is how React maintains hooks mappings. This is just to give an idea of hooks implementation.

```js
const MyReact = (function() {
  let hooks = [],
    currentHook = 0 // array of hooks, and an iterator!
  return {
    render(Component) {
      const Comp = Component() // run effects
      Comp.render()
      currentHook = 0 // reset for next render
      return Comp
    },
    useEffect(callback, depArray) {
      const hasNoDeps = !depArray
      const deps = hooks[currentHook] // type: array | undefined
      const hasChangedDeps = deps ? !depArray.every((el, i) => el === deps[i]) : true
      if (hasNoDeps || hasChangedDeps) {
        callback()
        hooks[currentHook] = depArray
      }
      currentHook++ // done with this hook
    },
    useState(initialValue) {
      hooks[currentHook] = hooks[currentHook] || initialValue // type: any
      const setStateHookIndex = currentHook // for setState's closure!
      const setState = newState => (hooks[setStateHookIndex] = newState)
      return [hooks[currentHook++], setState]
    }
  }
})()
```

You can read more about how [hooks](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/03/11/deep-dive-how-do-react-hooks-really-work/) works in React here.